# Any resources on implementing auto complete for a not well used language

Tags: autocompletion

I am working on a large ColdFusion project. I was using intellij since it had a linter and autocomplete for this language. I did find a ColdFusion mode but, that was only for syntax. Is there anyway I could form some type of dictionary and add functions as I go along? I think the autocomplete for intellij is closed source :(

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/doc/manual.md#extend?

Comment: [company-mode](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode) has some info on [writing backends](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/wiki/Writing-backends) including a linked article that seems useful, if you wanted to go that route.